# Automatically convert all dates in $.AJAX response

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, ajax, json.net

I'm doing ajax request to my ASP.NET MVC application using jQuery, and in "success" handler I receive an object with dates in ISO-8601 format serialized using Json.NET:

```
response = {
  FirstDate: "2001-11-11T00:00:00Z"
  SecondDate: "2002-22-22T00:00:00Z"
}
```

After that I need manually convert all these dates before I can use them:

```
var firstParsedDate = new Date(response.MyDate);
var secondParsedDate = new Date(response.MyDate);
```

Is there any way to receive a response object with already parsed dates?
If not, can they be parsed all at once?

Comment: How would you determine whether a particular property is a date or not? JavaScript just sees them as strings. If you can figure that out, you could do something with jQuery's [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) settings, probably the `converters` property, where you can override its use of `jQuery.parseJSON`.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, I can test all strings in the response using ISO 8061 regex. If this conversion can be performed using ajax settings it would be a nice solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a recursive function that will go through the response object and automatically convert any strings matching the ISO 8601 format into Date objects.  Something like this should work:

```
function replaceIso8601StringsWithDates(obj)
{
    if (obj !== null && typeof (obj) === "object" && !Array.isArray(obj)) {
        for (var prop in obj) {
            if (isIso8601String(obj[prop])) {
                obj[prop] = new Date(obj[prop]);
            }
            else {
                replaceIso8601StringsWithDates(obj[prop]);
            }
        }
    }
}

var iso8601Regex = /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(\.\d{1,6})?(Z|[+-]\d{2}:\d{2})$/;
function isIso8601String(val) {
    return typeof (val) === "string" && iso8601Regex.test(val);
}
```

Then in your `success` handler you just need to call the function:

```
function success(data, status, xhr) {
    replaceIso8601StringsWithDates(data);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery's [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to perform a function on each value.
For demonstration purposes, I've added [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString).

```js
response = {
  FirstDate: "2001-11-11T00:00:00Z",
  SecondDate: "2002-22-22T00:00:00Z"
}

$.each(response,function(i, v) {
  response[i]=new Date(v).toString();
});

console.log(response);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Here's an alternative example using [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) that excludes invalid dates:

```js
var response = {
    FirstDate: "2001-11-11T00:00:00Z",
    SecondDate: "2002-22-22T00:00:00Z",
    ThirdDate: "1995-08-22T05:23Z",
  },

  valid_dates = $.map(response, function(v, i) {
    return Date.parse(v) ? new Date(v).toString() : null;
  });

console.log(valid_dates);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If there are any non-Date properties in the response, those will be set to an invalid Date object...